# which camera glasses allow recording while connected to power source

Tags: video-capture

I am trying to use camera glasses for documenting benchwork.

Most of available models allow 1 to max 2h hours of recording for as long as the battery lasts and only allow next recording after the battery is recharged (3h).

I need either to continuously stream or to make long recordings with low frame rate (5/second). I don't mind walking around with a bunch of wires or having a power supply connected continuously to the glasses.

Can somebody recommened a model of camera glasses or perhaps a clipon camera which allows to adjust frame rate, allows streaming (that is optional) but most importantly allows recording while connected to power source.

Thanks so much in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

A GoPro camera can be connected to a power source and can record for a long time.  There are numerous ways to attach one to your head (or safety goggles).

Comment: Thanks so much for responding. I'll consider using the GoPro. I was thoughtthinking of something less bulky. Besides I need to record what a technitian is doing literally with his hands. I assume the GoPro would provide more of a "from top" type of view.

Comment: n.b.  The best way to express thanks is by actually up-voting a useful answer.  Merely saying thanks is actually a good way to get your comment deleted (across all of stackexchange, not just the video group).

Comment: I tried voting your asnwer up a couple of times – it says " Votes cast with less then 15 reputation are recorded but do not change publicly displayed score ". Sorry about that. Despite what you say I still believe in the eternal power of good old " thank you " :)